# What is the global scope in javascript? How can I create one?

Tags: javascript, global-scope

When running code on Chrome Inspector's console and typing the `this` keyword, I can see the global scope object that is exposed with many properties already set. But, how can I create mine? Or when I call a function, the call-site is the "global scope" of that function?

I'm reading YDKJS book series and some concepts get really confusing sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

First of all Kyle Simpson's series [**You Don't Know JavaScript**](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS) is very nice.  Few know that topic as well as he does.

Second, in the context of a browser, what you are calling global variables are all variables that are owned by the [**Window**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object.  So, keep that in mind when **naming** them so you don't clobber an existing and important property.

Third, [learn more JavaScript](https://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices) and realize you can generally avoid using these types of **variables**